# Alternative to wp_update_post() in Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to write a Wordpress Plugin in PHP to auto-update content on multiple pages.
I managed to make it work, it updates correctly, however it breaks multiple page options (controlled by the theme). I believe it's caused by the `wp_update_post()` function.

I'm looking for the REST API equivalent of this, since it works successfully when I tried with Python.

```
<?php
.
..
... 
             $new_content = str_replace($old_data, $new_data, $content);
             $edited_post = ['ID'=> $pageID, 'post_content' => $new_content];
             wp_update_post( $edited_post);
```

Thank you !

Comment: Those three lines of code you shared only update the `post_content` field though. How are they "breaking multiple page options" exactly? Which options?

Comment: Well that's what I'm wondering, the theme used is Uncode and for some reason when the plugin is triggered, the Page Header (including its background) disappears. I have to add them back manually using the "Page options" in the bottom of the page, it's not technically part of the page content itself. Using REST, it doesn't happen, but I couldn't get it to work on PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :

```
                 wp_set_current_user(1); // IMPORTANT FOR CRONJOB
                 $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'PUT', '/wp/v2/pages/'.$pageID );
                 $request->set_query_params( [ 'content' => $new_content ] );
                 $rest_response = rest_do_request($request);
                 wp_set_current_user(0);
```

In case someone needs it ;)